# Cannot display aws s3 image url in react-native android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, amazon-s3

The Image component does not display/render the AWS S3 image url on react native Android but does so for iOS.

In the S3 bucket, I selected 'make public' for the object and also made the bucket public hence the image is rendered on iOS.

**Image is displayed - Android**

```
<View>
        <Image source={{ uri: 'https://houseofhargrove.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Beautiful-Exteriors1.jpg' }} style={Styles.itemImgBig} />
        <View style={Styles.itemNoCrv}></View>
        <Icon name="heart" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={Styles.itemFavorite} />
    </View>
```

**Image NOT displayed - Android**

```
<View>
        <Image source={{ uri: 'https://bulooka-images.s3.amazonaws.com/properties/Beautiful-Exteriors1.jpg' }} style={Styles.itemImgBig} />
        <View style={Styles.itemNoCrv}></View>
        <Icon name="heart" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={Styles.itemFavorite} />
    </View>
```

**Image is displayed - iOS**

```
<View>
        <Image source={{ uri: 'https://bulooka-images.s3.amazonaws.com/properties/Beautiful-Exteriors1.jpg' }} style={Styles.itemImgBig} />
        <View style={Styles.itemNoCrv}></View>
        <Icon name="heart" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={Styles.itemFavorite} />
    </View>
```

I'm stumped as to where to start troubleshooting. Since the S3 image url is displayed in IOS, what else in S3 might cause this behavior?

Comment: S3 is not the culprit, found an S3 image link that display on react-native Android...`https://bulooka-images.s3.amazonaws.com/properties/house-for-sale-in-kitende-f6a85b085ebfff12e6502969655d1e34-s.jpg`

Comment: Exact same problem.. any news?

Comment: Any update on this having a similar issue on ios